# How to make multiples text Overlays

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following problem: I am trying to make multiples Overlays and it just does not work. It always shows only the last one as an overlay. Even when i put different "id" when i press the first button or second button - i will the overlay2, i never can see overlay1 when i press id "overlay1" How can I make it work?

```js
function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay1").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay1").style.display = "none";
}

function on() {
  document.getElementById("overlay2").style.display = "block";
}

function off() {
  document.getElementById("overlay2").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#overlay1 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#overlay2 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay1" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text1">Overlayy878 Text</div>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <h2>Overlay with Text</h2>
  <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
</div>



<div id="overlay2" onclick="off()">
  <div id="text2">Overlay 2 TWO Text</div>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <h2>Overlay with Text</h2>
  <button onclick="on()">Turn on overlay effect</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're defining multiple functions with the same name - at the same level. The second defintion for **on()** & **off()** toggles the visibility for overlay2 and since it appears later in your script it overwrites the first definitions which would have controlled overlay1.

To workaround this just define those two functions once and add an additional parameter which will determine if you want to toggle overlay1 or overlay2.

```
<button onclick="on(1)">Turn on overlay effect</button> // to toggle overlay1
<button onclick="on(2)">Turn on overlay effect</button> // to toggle overlay2
<div id="overlay1" onclick="off(1)"> // hide overlay1
<div id="overlay2" onclick="off(2)"> // hide overlay2
```

Here's the complete example:

```js
function on(param) {
  document.getElementById("overlay" + param).style.display = "block";
}

function off(param) {
  document.getElementById("overlay" + param).style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#overlay1 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#overlay2 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay1" onclick="off(1)">
  <div id="text1">Overlayy878 Text</div>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <h2>Overlay with Text</h2>
  <button onclick="on(1)">Turn on overlay effect</button>
</div>



<div id="overlay2" onclick="off(2)">
  <div id="text2">Overlay 2 TWO Text</div>
</div>

<div style="padding:20px">
  <h2>Overlay with Text</h2>
  <button onclick="on(2)">Turn on overlay effect</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah - sorry - I forgot to add the parameter (1 or 2) to the overlay divs. I fixed the example in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```js
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("overlay1").style.display = "block";
})

document.getElementById('overlay1').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("overlay1").style.display = "none";
})

document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("overlay2").style.display = "block";
})

document.getElementById('overlay2').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("overlay2").style.display = "none";
})
```

```css
#overlay1 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#overlay2 {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#text2{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay1">
        <div id="text1">Overlayy878 Text</div>
    </div>
      
    <div style="padding:20px">
        <h2>Overlay with Text</h2>
        <button id="btn1">Turn on overlay effect</button>
    </div>
      
     
    <div id="overlay2">
        <div id="text2">Overlay 2 TWO Text</div>
    </div>
      
    <div style="padding:20px">
        <h2>Overlay with Text</h2>
        <button id="btn2" >Turn on overlay effect</button>
    </div>
```